How to pass an element from a limited list as input?
I possess a compilation of the different states of arm within the game "rock paper scissors". My intention is to program these categories in a similar manner as this.
[1, 0, 0] - rock 
[0, 1, 0] - paper 
[0, 0, 1] - scissors

is there a convenient automatic way?
I employed the Embedding layer, but I'm uncertain if it's appropriate.

index = 2
categories_length = 3

tensor = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(
    torch.LongTensor([index]),
    categories_length,
)

Another pretty way:
rock, paper, scissors = torch.eye(3) 

